# Active Directory Group not appearing on a new server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I have a group of users in AD which reside at DOMAIN\mediapeople and i can assign this group to a share, like i have done on to a file share on the domain controller.

I have a new server, which also hosts some large media files, (this is it's purpose). I wish to add this group DOMAIN\mediapeople to this new share, but it is not available? I have a RDP session open to the main server, and also this secondary server, logged in with the same credentials, and this security group is available to one server, but not the other This is the first I have ever seen this, and I am wondering if anyone else has ever seen this before?

Comment: Have you joined the new server to AD?

Comment: Yes, the server is part of the domain.

Comment: Just to add some more information. The server in question has no roles on the domain, it is just a server that has been joined to the domain. I noticed that the active directory snap in is not available on this system, (because AD isn't on this box, i'm guessing!). I'm beginning to think that this server may need to be added to the same groups as the domain controller, although i'm reluctant to start just playing around with stuff!

Comment: The Active Directory snapins are only installed on domain controllers per default. The member server does not need these to operate correctly. You do -not- want to add your new server into the domain controllers group or OU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the answer to this one was I wasn't using universal security groups. Once I'd changed the groups to universal, the appear as expected

Answer (score 6):

This might be an indiciation that you're having bigger problems with Active Directory not replicating... if one of your fileservers is using 'DC1' and the other fileserver is using DC2 to answer queries and DC1 <-> DC2 replication is broken, you'd see this problem.

I'd go take a look at 'AD Sites and Services' on both your domain controllers, and make sure you can force replication.

Here's how to do that, straight from MS: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776188%28WS.10%29.aspx

If you get an error instead of the message "Active Directory has replicated the connections" you've got bigger AD level problems to deal with...

Comment: this isn't something that I considered. I will look into this and get back to you, thanks for the tip.

Comment: This answer is wrong - It wasn't AD not replicating or anything like that, it was using global groups instead of universal groups, a quick change in AD, and it was all working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you're entering the group name, is the location set to your domain?  And the type of object is set to users/groups?  Can you add other arbitrary AD groups(from the same domain & OU)?

Comment: The location is set correctly, this domain is actually has a trust with another domain, setting the location correctly is something I drill into all the techies, because it gives me a headache! Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the file server joined to the domain, and that when on the file server trying to add the group to the share's permissions, that your location is set to the domain and that the objects you are searching include groups.

Comment: I've already checked all these things, which is why i'm surprised, some group appear, and other do not? This is very weird for me, because i have done this many times before :)

Comment: As Eric says in his answer, there may be something bigger going on.  What does your domain structure look like?  How many DCs?  How many sites?

Answer (score 0):

If the DNS settings are not correct on the new server, it will not list AD groups or users in the security dialog.

Make sure your new server is using your domain controller for DNS

Comment: I've changed the DNS settings to point directly to the domain controller, which is running DNS instead of the general DNS for the network. I'll let you know how that gets on.